# Tracking location of an object in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using Javafx to make a top down scroller game where the player can move left and right. I'm trying to give the player the capability to fire projectiles, but so far, whenever they are fired, they only move from the spot where the player starts, which is the center. Even if I move left or right, the projectiles still originate from the center. Both the projectiles and the player are Circle objects, and I'm using the `Player.getCenterX()` method to find out where the player is at any time and then set the start location of the projectile to that location.

I use this line to move the player left or right

```
myPlayer.setTranslateX(myPlayer.getTranslateX()  + myPlayer.getSpeed())
```

Something doesn't work. Does the `.setTranslateX()` method not change the player's center location? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As you said your using Player.getcenterX() will provide the forward and backward change locationas you specified center if you want to move lef or right then you can go with Point2D or Point3D packages in javafx. 
It will have easy processing the location fastly and easy to understand. Over if your game is 2D or 3D game. 
Try to go with these reference.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand what you're saying. I can't seem to get it to take into account the transformations that have been applied. Will the Point2D package fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of translating the circle, relocate it by updating the center location for the circle.

For example:

```
myPlayer.setCenterX(myPlayer.getCenterX() + myPlayer.getSpeed())
```

Then you can always determine the x location of the center of your circle by calling:

```
myPlayer.getCenterX();
```

Translation is usually used for temporary transitions and animations, but you aren't really doing that here, you are moving the player around permanently, so relocation is a better approach.  If you did stick with translation rather than relocating the center as I suggest, then read up on the bounding rectangle information in the [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) documentation, especially try to understand [boundsInParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty--).